# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract[dup]

Tags: java, sorting, date, comparator

After trying for 3 hours all the solutiond that I found with no success, I'm posting my issue here. I am getting the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

This is my code:

```
public int compare(InstrumentModel o1, InstrumentModel o2) {
    int c = 0;
    if(c == 0 && o1.getUnderlyingAsset()!=null) {
        c = o1.getUnderlyingAsset().compareTo(o2.getUnderlyingAsset());
    }
    if(c == 0 && o1.getSymbol()!=null) {
        c = o1.getSymbol().compareTo(o2.getSymbol());
    }
    if(c == 0 && o1.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null && o2.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;
        try {
            date1 = df.parse(df.format(o1.getExpiryDateInDate()));
            date2 = df.parse(df.format(o2.getExpiryDateInDate()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c = date1.before(date2) ? 1 : date1.after(date2) ? -1 : 0 ;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing the exception ?

Comment: @vincrichaud line number is not printed in exception. this method is inside a custom comparator class. stack trace telling the line number from Collections.sort(list, new ExpiryComparator()) only.  sorting based on underlyingasset, then symbol and lastly on expirydateindate properties. If I remove expirydateindate here, then records are sorted as expected manner.

Comment: @Berger Could you please help me to understand the line from the post: One way to satisfy the transitivity requirement in compareParents() is to traverse the getParent() chain instead of only looking at the immediate ancestor.

Comment: @mayukhg it means to test also `getParent().getParent()` and `getPArent().getParent().getParent()` and so on, until there is no more parent. Then you'll have covered all cases and can't violate the contract

Comment: Below suggestion worked for me by checking null values.

Comment: Other issues with your code (ignore if not interested): Does formatting the date and parsing it back buy you anything? Your format pattern string is wrong, use uppercase `MM` for month (or sorting dates from different months won’t work). Consider dropping the long outdated `Date` and the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You have bad handling of null values.

If one of the compared `InstrumentModel`s has a `null` `getExpiryDateInDate` and the other has a non null value, you should not return 0.

You should be consistent. For example:

- if both are null, return 0
- if `o1.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null` && `o2.getExpiryDateInDate()==null`, return `1`
- if `o1.getExpiryDateInDate()==null` && `o2.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null`, return -1.
- finally, only if both are not `null` run your date comparison code to determine what to return.

Note: Your `null` handling of the asset and symbol properties also doesn't look good, but perhaps they are never `null` (or at least if one has a value, the other also has a value). Otherwise, comparisons such as `o1.getUnderlyingAsset().compareTo(o2.getUnderlyingAsset())` could lead to trouble if `o2.getUnderlyingAsset()` is `null` (depending on the type of `getUnderlyingAsset()` and how it implements `compareTo`).

Comment: thank you!! this suggestion works. I checked null values for  expirydateindate field as you suggested.

Comment: If this was the problem, how come the asker didn’t see any `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @OleV.V. `if(c == 0 && o1.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null && o2.getExpiryDateInDate()!=null)`. Based on the OP's comments there was only an issue with the comparison of the expiry dates. No risk of NPE there.

Comment: Thanks, that explains. I obviously didn’t read the code closely enough the first time.

Comment: You may take advantage of [`Comparator.nullsFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) (or `nullsLast`).